# Custom property descriptor and flattening hierarchies

Tags: c#, binding, propertydescriptor

I have a custom property descriptor that I use to support flattening object hierarchies.

To accomplish this I subclassed `PropertyDescriptor` and I store a linked list to the "next" (child) property that I want to retrieve the value for.

This enables me to bind subproperties to a grid(export to excel, whatever) in a "flat" manner.

eg.
    Grid(bound Property, Caption)

```
Col1:Customer.Name(Customer)
Col2:Customer.Address(Address)
Col3:Customer.OutstandingOrders.Count(Outstanding Orders)
```

The problem is that once I add in a column with a duplicate name, regardless of the fact it's got a unique caption it will retrieve the property for the 1st one but still put the correct header in:

```
Col4:Customer.Company.Name(Company)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that once I add in a column with a duplicate name, regardless of the fact it's got a unique caption it will retrieve the property for the 1st one but still put the correct header in.

Can you clarify that line? I've done this before, but I used the navigation path in the imaginary name - i.e. I might have the `PropertyDescriptor.Name` report `Customer_Company_Name` rather than `Name`, and use the `.DisplayName` to report something more readable.

Comment: Ahh, I see,
I'll try this, I currently return the last child's name (ie this.child==null ? this.name : this.child.name;
I'll try it building a unique name like that as I think it's caching the value for the first property and reusing it with the correct caption on the 2nd property.
I would vote you up but I cant :(
I'll let you know.

Comment: This is the new working line in the Name override.
return base.Name + (childProperty == null ? "" : "_" + childProperty.Name);
I was previously returning base.Name if childProperty == null or childProperty.Name elsewise.